# How to set a password variable via a script for mounting a cifs share

Tags: bash, nas, cifs

I have the following bash script to mount a couple of shared directories in a NAS drive:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server/dir1 /mnt/nas/dir1 -o username=raf
sudo mount -t cifs //server/dir2 /mnt/nas/dir2 -o username=raf
sudo mount -t cifs //server/dir3 /mnt/nas/dir3 -o username=raf
```

Each of these mount commands will ask for a password. I want to avoid having to enter the same password multiple times.

From `mount.cifs` manual, it says that it can use the variable `PASSWD` for the password.

That's where my bash skills fail me: how can I update the script to ask and set the `PASSWD` variable, call the `mount` commands, and finally unset the `PASSWD` variable?

So far I could go as far as reading something without echoing back to screen using

```
read -s PASSWD
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the script.

Note 1: The `mount` argument `-o password=password` is a no go for me. I don't want hard coded passwords in a text file.

Note 2: Similarly, I'd rather not go for the `mount` argument `credentials=filename`

Comment: See: [How do I pass credential file to mount.cifs?](https://serverfault.com/q/367934/234750)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the variable is not seen by child process. You can export the `PASSWD` using `export`

```
read -s PASSWD
export PASSWD
```

Note: This makes it available to all the child process. For your purposes, what you need is simply export the variable only to concerned child process.

```
sudo PASSWD="$PASSWD" mount -t cifs //server/dir3 /mnt/nas/dir3 -o username=raf
```

Comment: `sudo` complicates matters; you can't put the assignment before `mount`, and `sudo` doesn't (by default) pass its own environment onto the program it runs.

Comment: @chepner: It seems you can. @Vivek's suggestion in the note worked perfectly fine for me: `sudo PASSWD="$PASSWD" mount ...`

Comment: Now, at the end, do I need to `unset PASSWD` ?

Comment: @Raf Ah, I didn't read `man sudo` closely enough; I assumed that since the command had to be an executable (not a shell function or arbitrary shell command), that precommand modifiers weren't permitted either.

Comment: Since `PASSWD="$PASSWD"` is part of the command line now, it ends up being visible in the process table for all users (e.g. `ps` output). It is safer to move the variable definition in front of `sudo` and use the `-E` option to inherit it, i.e. `PASSWD="$PASSWD" sudo -E mount ...`

Comment: @GrishaLevit thanks for pointing that out, this is an important security flaw. However when doing a `ps -A`, or `ps -e`, I can see only the main process name, and not the `PASSWD` variable definition. Which syntax did you use exactly to be able to see it?

Comment: @Raf the variable definition shows up as part of the `sudo` process entry, not the child process that sudo launches. I tried with `sudo var=foo sleep 60 &`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar and ended up writing a python utility called 'cifscloak'

With cifscloak, the password is stored encrypted in a sqlite database.

Really simple to use:

> sudo cifsfs addmount -n films -s myfilms -m /mnt/films -i myfileserver -o "ro" -u cifsuser

> sudo cifsfs addmount -n games -s mygames -m /mnt/games -i myfileserver -u cifsuser

> sudo cifsfs mount -a

To mount the filesystem at boot, cifscloak can be used to create a systemd file:

> cifscloak systemdfile -a

Take a look, see if it works for you:

https://github.com/sudoofus/cifscloak

pip install cifscloak